# Nivo Slider - Displaying All Gallery Images Stacked

Tags: nivo-slider

I have Nivo Gallery running well in a Drupal 7 installation on my live server and one of my two local environments (two computers) but on one, instead of displaying one image correctly and transitioning well, it shows all the images from the gallery stacked one on top of the next in the order that they are listed in the configuration in the Drupal 7 installation.

I would like to get it corrected in that local environment that is misbehaving, but after a couple of hours of flushing caches, disabling and reenabling the module, and searching the web, I am at a loss as to why it is performing like this. And it is only happening on one machine and across my various browsers on that machine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the site? we need something to help you out

Comment: Thanks for the response dippas. First ... it is working correctly on live server. It is working incorrectly on localhost. You understood that? The site is www.MurfreesboroPawnAndGun.com